# Amatic SC normal 700 - rendering issue with question mark character?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm using the *Amatic SC 700 normal* from google fonts.
This is the link on google fonts : https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Amatic+SC .

The issue is that right now the char `?` is converted in `®` .

The css code I used is:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:400,700);

body {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

The html looks like this :

```
 <html> ???? </html>
```

This is a screenshot of the issue : 
[image]

This is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/m4vev43a/

I tested this issue on:

- Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90
- Firefox 37.0.1
- Opera 12.16

Any idea how I can fix this?
Are my browsers getting crazy?
Or it's a bug in the font?

**Update:**

When using :

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC);
```

So without the suffix `:400,700` the question mark character is displayed properly.

Unfortunately using the above code + bold text is totaly messing up with the letter spacing in Chrome, Firefox, Opera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with the bold version of the Amatic font, as can be seen in this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=93) from November, 2011. Your font was implemented correctly, it's just that the font file itself has a bug.

A workaround is to use the regular variant for question marks. I know that's hardly a great solution but it seems there's not much else you can do.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround I've used to recover this situation.

**Note:** is not perfect if you need to trust the letter spacing for each browser.

Actually the idea is :

- define again the Amatic font in addition the std one, but without the :700
- generate a special class to handle just the sentences with the question mark

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Amatic';
    src: url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/amaticsc/v6/DPPfSFKxRTXvae2bKDzp5FtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/amaticsc/v6/DPPfSFKxRTXvae2bKDzp5D8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}

.has-question-mark {
    font-family: Amatic;
}
```